# Change my php $_POST form to a proper js / jQuery, Ajax no refresh needed form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have seen hundreds of these questions on stackoverflow and none really explain in detail how its done step by step.  I am still learning JS but I cannot find anything that shows step by step tutorial style how this is done.  There are dozens, upwards of 70 questions asking how to implement this and most have no best answer chosen.  So this is a generic form - using PHP $_POST that I would love to get some help with.  I want to have this form refresh two divs.   Here is my code;

```
<!-- This <form> for ENTERING measurements and SELECTING picture -->
<form name="log_data" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" />
<input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="<?php echo $current_user->ID; ?>"/>
<input type="number" step="any" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Length" name="length" value="" required="required"/>
<br />
<input type="number" step="any" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Ground" name="ground" value="" required="required"/>
<br />
<label for="date">Week Of:</label>
<input type="date" name="date" class="form-control" value="" required="required"/>
<br />
<input type="file" name="file" class="form-control" value="" />
<br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-primary"/>
</form>


<?php
$post_id = NULL;
if(!empty($_FILES['file']['name'])) { //new code to fix string error
foreach ($_FILES as $file => $array) 
{
$newupload = insert_attachment($file,$post_id); 
}
} else { $newupload = '';} //new code to fix string error
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{ 
$wpdb->insert(wp_jo_plugin_options, array (
'user_id' => $_POST['user_id'],
'length'  => $_POST['length'],
'ground'  => $_POST['ground'],
'date'    => $_POST['date'],
'file' => $newupload
) );
}
?>
```

the form needs to update two divs. One named results_chart, and one named data_table.   The idea is to do this without a page refresh.  I currently use wordpress, and this is for a plugin. Additionally, I use ISSET to post, without a separate file. That may need to change based on what I read about implementing this feature.

The $newupload controls inserting a pictures post-id into a separate table. I am aware of the lack of validation in place, I am not to sure how to implement that so instead I took the JS validation approach.

Answer (score 2):

NetTuts+ has a good tutorial as well:

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/submit-a-form-without-page-refresh-using-jquery/

Comment: Yea I tried that but I need mine to use the $_POST function to store data in a table as well as upload a file, and refresh two separate divs.  That tutorial is very simplistic.

Comment: That example is using post. The Ajax request is sent via a post request, and the data item is setup to be your query string that gets posted. You should be able to use jquery to setup your data string that you want posted. After that, your php file will process the $_POST variable for the values you need to save, then return either a json, xml, or html return value to the calling javascript, which in turn you can use to update your divs.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
    async: false,
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    url: '/locationOfYourPHPFunction',
    data: $('#form').serializeArray(),
    success: function(__data) {
        $('#firstDiv').html(__data.firstThing);
        $('#secondDiv').html(__data.secondThing);
    };
});
```

You must have your function that that is giving the post data to the AJAX call `return json_encode($data);` so that the format will be output properly. This assumes you have an associative array with the keys firstThing and secondThing. (e.g. `array('first' => '', 'second' => '');`).

`async` tell the AJAX function to not run these in unison, depending on what you're running this can make things not work properly.

`.serializeArray()` looks for your form that contains the id `form` and sends that data. Data can be appended to that array by pushing in JSON format: `({country: 'DE', time: '12:00'});`

All this can be placed in a js function to be called onclick="" or through a jQuery().click();.

If you are using a framework like CakePHP make sure to place `$this->autoRender = false;` at the beginning of the function, otherwise you will run into problems.

EDIT: I missed the using wordpress part, all is still relevant but I would highly recommend to stop using wordpress. It's terribly unsecure, poorly structured, bloated and unfriendly for SEO & ones' sanity.

Comment: Thank you for your input Sam!  I agree with you on the sanity note.  I learned PHP and PDO then went to code in WP and quickly learned I had to go backwards to learn mysqli as wordpress does not support PDO, and anything I want accomplished requires wp inbuilt functions.

Comment: Has the example and explained AJAX request helped?